# mongodb unique index based on set of array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Say if I have the document:

```
{ accounts: [1, 2] }
```

I should not be able to add a new document

```
{ accounts: [2, 1] }
```

but I should be able to add

```
{ accounts: [1, 3] }
```

is there some way to create a unique index like this? My current solution is to check that it's a subset is not already defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator building your query condition,

```
db.col.update({ accounts: { $not: { $all: [2, 1] } } }, { $push: { accounts: { $each: [ 2, 1 ] } } }) // will return no match
```

while

```
db.col.update({ accounts: { $not: { $all: [1, 3] } } }, { $push: { accounts: { $each: [ 1, 3 ] } } })
```

will succesfully update your document since not all elements are present in `accounts` array

EDIT:
To prevent inserting the document you need an index with `unique` parameter. By default MongoDB creates separate index entries for every element of the array which means that you will be able to insert `1` only once. As a workaroung you can try to create compound index using array index:

```
db.col.createIndex( { "accounts.0": 1, "accounts.1": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

This requires pairs of numbers to be unique but order matters here so you have to enforce your application to insert `accounts` as ordered array.

Comment: Ah sorry i meant add it as a new document in a collection.

Comment: @A.Lau modified my answer, this is kind of workaround so I'm not sure if that helps in your case

Comment: unfortunately the order does matter, as I'm doing a kind of friends connection thing. So the first element is always the requester and the second element is the requestee. So if the status is "pending", then the second element should be the user who has the "accept" and "decline" option, while the first element would only get the "cancel" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using $addToSet. It will ensure that the array contains all unique values.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

unique indexes (arrays included) are described pretty well in Mongo's docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/), did you read them?

BTW if you explain the problem, you would get better feedback.

I guess your solution could work if you don't need to have > 1 document with null key (consult the manual). Arrays are treated as sets, so if [1, 2] is present, [2, 1] will be rejected in the presence of unique index.

Comment: how about you read the most upvoted answer first before posting your own answer?